# Facebook SDK 4.1 for Swift. Single button to be used for share and login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a YouTube player in my app and I am trying to add a Facebook share button on it, so users would be able to share the youtube videos.

I am using Facebook SDK 4.1 and I have successfully implemented the Login and Share functions. But for now if I need to firstly login and than share the link.

How can I merge these two processes so I will have only Share button and when this button is clicked if the user has not login than login view will be shown, if he has than the link would be shared. So I need somehow to call the login function in share button. But since I am new in swift I can’t see where are the on click actions here or how can I implement the login function without clicking the login button.

Here is my code:

```
let contentURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBsPZV14I-k"
let contentURLImage = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/jBsPZV14I-k/0.jpg"
let contentTitle = "sdasfdfsa"
let contentDescription = "asdsadasdasd"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {   
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self
        self.returnUserData()
        self.showShareButtons()
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self  
    }
}

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    println("User Logged In")

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
        {
            // Do work
        }
        self.returnUserData()
        self.showShareButtons()
    }  
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
}

func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in   
        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            println("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}

func showShareButtons()
{
    self.showLinkButton()
}

func showLinkButton()
{
    let content : FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: self.contentURL)
    content.contentTitle = self.contentTitle
    content.contentDescription = self.contentDescription
    content.imageURL = NSURL(string: self.contentURLImage)

    let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
    button.shareContent = content
    button.frame = CGRectMake((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 100) * 0.5, 50, 100, 25)
    self.view.addSubview(button) 
}
```

Comment: you can store what you want to share somewhere.  check if you have successfully logged in and then post that event.

Comment: I am not sure how u mean store what u want somewhere, because the link is stored in a variable if u thought so.

Comment: that could be anything but you need to have something for SHARE and that content might be owned by some other target. So saving its somewhere (as a file or an object) meant 'store what you want to share' somewhere (an object or a file). Here you have it as a string object.

Comment: just check when you get responce that user is successfully logged in , retrieve your data , make a post and share.

Comment: So u are saying to use only login button and with that button when the users has log in to share link? But is there a way to change the look of the login button (make it as a share button) because I can not find a way to do so. I do not know where that button is created

Comment: No just call share event (only once) when the user is successfully logged in. You don't need to change button until next load. When user reloaded the page or by any other event first check if user is logged in or not if he or she is already logged in just show share button.

Comment: can you make these changes in the code above ?

Comment: i can't (no swift knowledge ). But posting code for Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I did this work for sharing when user is not logged in but still he tap the share button. I poped up the FBLogin Window and when user finished logged in successfully, i use this code for share the game score. Note that this function only works once (or on after re-login).

This is delegate method of FB Framework. It will get response when the state of user log in changed.

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen)
    {
        //log in

        NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSArray *arr=[def objectForKey:@"fbShare"];
        if (arr.count>0)
        {
            int score=[[arr objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
            int hScore=[[arr objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
            int level=[[arr objectAtIndex:2]intValue];
            BOOL isArcade=[[arr objectAtIndex:3] boolValue];
            ShareScoreFB *share=[[ShareScoreFB alloc]init];
            [share shareToFacebookCurrentScore:score andHighScore:hScore forLevel:level forArcade:isArcade];
            [def removeObjectForKey:@"fbShare"];
            [def synchronize];
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not know anything on Obj-C and also what I understand I have achieved something similar before. I need somehow to vanish the login button and have only share button always. And if u are login than share button will be shown always not only once. But thank you again

Comment: you can store the state of login flag from here.  Use that flag when you are setting share (or login) button.